# Better screen resolution on debian server with no graphic card

Tags: display, xserver

I have a debian server (no graphic card), but using nomachine from a linux client I only get a 1024x768 screen resolution.

How do I get a better resolution?

Thank you!

Comment: No offense, but why do your care about screen resolution on a server? You should be connecting remotely via ssh.

Comment: Maybe he need a RDP.

Comment: @Skamasle - RDP doesn't care what the console resolution is. The client determines the resolution.

Comment: @Skamasle - RDP is for windows.  He has a Debian Linux server.

Comment: I want to work on the server with nomachine, and I need a better resolution than 1024x768

Comment: @Matt nothing is for windows only, If you whant remote desktop you can do it on Linux, centos, ubuntu, fedora, debian server, its the same, you only need install gnome or kde, and conect it whit nomachine client and you have a remote desktop same thing than on windows but on linux, so I use linux in home, and if I need remote desktop I dont whant do it whit windows, I install also linux.

Answer (score 0):

I use nomechine and always I get more than 1024x768

You only need configure your nomachine client and on configuration -> general -> display need change that, ( Custom, Available Area, Full Screen etc )

Whit that I always get same resolution than mi computer ( 1600x1200 whitout problems on dedicated server and VPS ( virtuozzo and KVM )

Comment: when I connect to the server with nomachine, my client doesn't permit me setting a better resolution than 1024x768

Comment: But you need configure your client before conect, What version of nomachine you have, currently I use 3.5 whitout problems.

Comment: I have nomachine 4.0.352

Comment: Maybe your problem is debian, if you use debian 7 or current testing you cant get bettner than that because you have gnome 3, try run gnome clasic or try to instal lxde or kde.

Comment: But does screen resolution depend on gnome/kde/lxde or on xserver itself?

Comment: Check this -> http://www.nomachine.com/AR06J00636 ( is old but maybe help, problom whit gnome)  and I say about gnome 3, because gnome 3 need more grafic power, and lxde is simpler, and I like say before i never had problems whit that, lxde, kde and gnome 2, whit gnome 3 never try because that versión dont work whit nomachine 3.5 client, maybe you want try whit nomachine client 3.5 and lxde :)